# Reducing an array with multiple condition need the clarity

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got this code with one of my office challange.

```
const arr = [5,10,15,'C','D', '+'];
```

1. 'C' remove the previous value from the array - now arr = [5,10,'D', '+'];
2. 'D  double the value in previous - now arr = [10,20,'+'];
3. '+' sums the value - now arr = [30]

I am trying to achieve this goal using `array` `reduce` method. but for me `D` is not console the value at all.

any one help me with correct way?
Here is my try:

```js
const arr = [5,10,15,'C','D', '+'];

const result = arr.reduce((c,v,i,a) => {
  if(v=='C'){
     a.splice(i-1, i-1);
  }
  if(v=='D'){
     console.log(i) //console not works
  }

  return c + (Number(v) ? v:0);
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6mR3OkcBqNXKZ4Cp?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const arr = [5, 10, 15, 'C', 'D', '+'];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr === 'C') {
    acc.pop(); // remove the previous value from the array
  } else if (curr === 'D') {
    acc= acc.map(x=>x*2); // double the value of the ALL elements
  } else if (curr === '+') {
    const sum = acc.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0); // sum all  
    return [sum]; // return the sum as a single element array
  } else {
    acc.push(curr); // add the current element to the accumulator
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `acc.pop();` removes the value from the end of the array, not at `i-1` (ie: the previous value)

Comment: @NickParsons Was about to say the same thing, but it's the `acc` (accumulator) array, not the global array, so I think it works for this case (since it's removing the last element that was added to the reduction value).

Comment: and I guess I made a mistake `acc[acc.length - 1] *= 2;` should not only double the last val but entire array. `acc.map(x=>x*2)`

Comment: @JackBashford Oh yep, you're right, my bad. So I suppose it is correct to use `.pop()` then (ltns btw)

Comment: I've updated with `acc.map(x=>x*2)` now returns 30 as requested and uses DOUBLE reduce :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using mappings:

```js
const arr = [5, 10, 15, 'C', 'D', '+'];

const functions = {
  'C': arr => arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1),
  'D': arr => arr.map(e => e * 2),
  '+': arr => [arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur)]
}

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (functions[cur]) {
    return functions[cur](acc);
  } else {
    return [...acc, cur];
  }
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `.slice(0, arr.length - 1)` can also be written as `.slice(0, -1)`

Answer (score 1):

when `v == "C"`, you splice the array taking out `15` and `"C"` making `"D"` takes the `"C"` place. so when reduce loops and runs again, the `"D"` get skipped and `v == "+"`.